# Parse string build.gradle contents to extract plugins and dependencies in java

Tags: java, gradle

I have a method in Java which gets the contents of a build.gradle file in String format as an argument. The method should be able to parse the content and read plugins and dependencies from it. The end-goal is to check whether a particular plugin/dependency is added in build.gradle file. Can someone suggest an efficient way of doing this in Java?

Here is a snippet of build.gradle file content (Actual content will be given as String):

```
plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" apply false
    id "org.sonarqube"
    id "org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint"
}
dependencies {
    implementation "joda-time:joda-time:2.2"
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"
}
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'hello.HelloWorld'

// tag::repositories[]
repositories { 
    mavenCentral() 
}
// end::repositories[]

// tag::jar[]
jar {
    archiveBaseName = 'gs-gradle'
    archiveVersion =  '0.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read in the file and use regex to extract what you want:

```
String buildFile = Files.readString(Path.of("build.gradle"));
String[] dependencies = buildFile.replaceAll("(?sm).*dependencies.*?\\{(.*?)^}.*", "$1").trim().split("\\s*\\R\\s*");
```

Result from your file:

```
[implementation "joda-time:joda-time:2.2", testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"]
```